# Integrate OpenCV using cmake - cannot open shared object file

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I am trying to integrate OpenCV (v4.1.2) into an existing project and I made below changes for that:

*CMakeLists.txt*

> ```
> find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED core imgcodecs imgproc PATHS <path to all opencv shared object files>)
> target_link_libraries(<exec name> ${OpenCV_LIBS})
> ```

Also added below to the config file:

> #cmakedefine HAVE_LIBOPENCV 1
>
> #cmakedefine HAVE_OPENCV_H 1

Copy the output executable at:

> /usr/bin

Run the below command to set rpath:

> patchelf --set-rpath path-to-opencv/opencv/lib:$ORIGIN /usr/bin/executablename

Below are the changes I added in the source code:

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("sample.jpg", ZM_MAX_IMAGE_COLOURS);
cv::imwrite("sample-opencv.jpg", img);
```

However, when I run the the code, I see below message in logs:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libopencv_imgproc.so.4.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Below are some sanity checks I performed on the executable file:

```
$readelf -d <executable name>

0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.1]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libopencv_core.so.4.1]
0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [<path to opencv>/opencv/lib:]

$ ldd <executable name>

libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.1 => <path to opencv>/opencv/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.1 (0x00007f49cf6f9000)
libopencv_core.so.4.1 => <path to opencv>/opencv/lib/libopencv_core.so.4.1 (0x00007f49ce4fc000)
libopencv_imgproc.so.4.1 => <path to opencv>/opencv/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.4.1 (0x00007f49c3b12000)
```

Even though there is a valid link in *ldd* output, *libopencv_imgproc.so*  doesn't exist in *readelf* output. My assumption is that since there is no source code directly consuming *imgproc*, it doesn't  show up in *readelf* output.

Can someone point out what is causing the "*cannot open shared object file*" error?

EDIT:
I changed my above code to include *imgproc* header and declare a class below as shown below:

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
cv::Subdiv2D div; // comes from imgproc
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("sample.jpg", ZM_MAX_IMAGE_COLOURS);
cv::imwrite("sample-opencv.jpg", img);
```

It worked after this change. Also, below is the new *readelf* output:

```
$ readelf -d <executable name>

 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libopencv_imgproc.so.4.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libopencv_core.so.4.1]
 0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [<path to opencv>/opencv/lib:]
```

However, it is just a workaround. One shouldn't need to write a placeholder code like this. Can someone help figure out a clean solution to include shared objects correctly?
FYI - Here are the internal dependecies between these opencv shared objects:

> libopencv_core --> no dependency
>
> libopencv_imgproc --> libopencv_core
>
> libopencv_imcodecs --> libopencv_core and libopencv_imgproc